# Should the percent symbol (%) always be HTML-escaped?

Tags: html, encoding

I know the percent symbol has to be URL-encoded when being passed around, but when I display it in the browser, is it also necessary to escape it like so: `&#37;`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In URLs, the percent sign (`%`) has a [special meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_encode#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters), so it should be escaped.  In HTML, it does not, so it is not necessary to escape it.

Answer (score 8):

I *agree* with the chosen answer, but would like to *qualify* the statement *“it is not necessary to escape it.”*

*If* you have a need (or desire) to escape a percentage sign in HTML code, (and there are *good* reasons to do this with *any* potentially ambiguous character or symbol) then I would *highly* recommend using the percentage entity code `&percnt;` as opposed to any numeric code. (those I use when there is no entity name you *could* use)

That was the answer I was looking for when I found this page, because I forgot it looses the final "e".

We should probably *all* be using *at least* the entities kindly listed [here](https://entitycode.com/#about-content). (whoever Webmasterish is; thank you)

**Reasoning:** Numeric codes (and particularly byte codes from unencoded characters) change with code–pages, on systems using different default languages, and / or different operating systems. (Windows and Mac using slightly different code sets for “English” being the classic, which *still* plagues plain–text eMail sent between Apple Mail and Outlook) This is slowing down, and *should* stop with UTF, but I'm *still* seeing it pop up.

If you're converting HTML to some other mark–up, (note, I used "`&ndash;`" not a "`-`", or even "`&minus;`" for the *same* reason) such as LaTeX, DVI, PostScript or even MarkDown, then it's useful to **completely** squash any ambiguity… And those processes tend to happen on the information you *least* expect to be used in such a way when you initially write it. So just get used to doing it *everywhere* and be grateful to your former self for having had the foresight to do so. Probably *years* down the line, when you're looking to update formulae to be more readable by utilising MathJax or such, and keep picking up hyphenated words. <swearmarks>

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add this - if you use javascript in href, you are in troubles too. Check this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/cs4MZ/

One of the workarounds might be using `onclick` instead of `href`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about in HTML text, visible to the reader, no. It can't do anything harmful, there.

...if you're talking about inside of HTML attributes, then yes, that would be good to consider.

URLs and HTML are different languages, as weird as that might seem, so they have different weaknesses.