# How to use in PHP variables enclosed in double percent(%%variable%%) inside of html

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm modifying an html file that gets sent to emails, I need to create some checks via **PHP** to the variables but **I don't know what the double percentages are**, I tried searching the net but the results I see does not even relate to programming.

I need to be sure when sending another mail since I can only see the output when the mail gets sent 30 mins later.

Sample code:

```
<img style="width: 160px; height: auto;" width="160" src="%%image_url_{{$i}}%%" alt="%%title_{{$i}}%%" style="margin:0.5em 1em 0 0"/>
```

Don't mind the curly braces, those are from Laravel blade template which is just a shortened , my problem is those %% %%. The data came from a csv.

I need to check the image_url via php

Comment: Looks like it's part of a template system, not PHP itself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851976/should-the-percent-symbol-always-be-html-escaped

Comment: why cant you just use some thing like this src="<?php $image_url_{{$i}} ?>"

Comment: No I know the template very well because I use Laravel and the double percent is not part of it.

First of all, I did not do this, so there should be a reason why it wasn't like what you said

Comment: question: does it work correctly as it is, with the double percent signs?

Comment: You say the data comes from the CSV. I think there is a laravel module that parses CSV using %%<data>%% as a way to parse the data. In fact it then is a basic templating methodology.

Answer (score 3):

Template systems simply replace those strings. Example:

```
// Object with variables
$vars = array(
    'image_url_1' => '/images/test.png';
    'image_url_2' => '/images/test2.png';
);

// Convert object with variables in "tags" ( so we dont have to parse per item )
foreach ($vars as &$value)
    $value = '%%' . $value . '%%';

$template = '/templates/test.html.tpl';

echo str_replace(file_get_contents($template), $vars);
```

The code above will parse `/templates/test.html.tpl` and will replace all `%%<var>%%` strings in the template with the values from $vars.

Hope this bit of code clears things up for you.