# What does %%SOMETEXT%% Mean in PHP form

Tags: javascript, php, forms

Today, I came to a PHP form using some variable/constant names or something else(I really don't know) in the following manner

```
<tr>
    <td align="left">Email Address<br>
        <input name="email" type="text" class="cartform" value="%%EMAIL%%" size="25">
        %%EMAILREQUIRED%%
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left">First Name<br>
        <input name="firstname" type="text" class="cartform" value="%%FIRSTNAME%%" size="25" onchange="setshipping()">
        %%FIRSTNAMEREQUIRED%%
    </td>
</tr>
```

Can anyone please explain the meaning of

```
value="%%EMAIL%%"
```

it displays the previously added email if the session is set, i.e it behaves like we are assigning the value of a variable in value attribute, but where I can find that where this variable/constant is declared/defined ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487920/how-to-use-in-php-variables-enclosed-in-double-percentvariable-inside-of-h

Comment: that will be some template system, its not native php